# to use same method of superclass for object of subclass

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
class A {
    void test() {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void test() {
    }

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
 B b=new B();
//insert code here
}
}
```

How can I call the `test` method of class A for  object **b** of class B ?
specifically for object b

Comment: Your method currently didn't have a return type, and your class declaration used `()` incorrectly - it's worth trying to make examples as complete as possible (without extraneous code, of course). It also helps if you put a bit of effort into formatting them nicely. I've fixed them this time, but please put more effort into future questions.

Comment: i will do it for next time but i was more concerned for concept

Comment: Yes, but invalid code distracts from the concept you're looking for. That's my point. You should put effort into making your question as easy for people to answer as possible. You're asking people to spend time helping you - you should show your appreciation for that by expressing your question as well as you can.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't call it from *outside* B... but *within* B you can call it as:

```
super.test();
```

This can be done from any code within B - it doesn't have to be in the `test()` method itself. So for example:

```
public void foo() {
    // Call the superclass implementation directly - no logging
    super.test();
}

@Override void test() {
    System.out.println("About to call super.test()");
    super.test();
    System.out.println("Call to super.test() complete");
}
```

Note the `@Override` annotation which tells the compiler that you really *did* mean to override a method. (Aside from anything else, if you have a typo in the method name, this will help you find it quickly.)

The reason you can't call it from outside B is that B *overrides* the method... the purpose of overriding is to replace the original behaviour. For example, in a method with a parameter, B may wish to do something with the parameter (validate it according to its own rules) before either calling the superclass implementation or doing something else. If outside code could just call A's version, that would violate B's expectations (and encapsulation).

Comment: @LewsTherin: Which bit? Overriding? The point is that overriding changes an object's behaviour. It would be pointless doing so if you could get round it by just casting to something else. Not only would it be unpleasant for the subclass, but it would remove the purpose of polymorphism itself: I want to be able to read from any InputStream *without* knowing its type, and still get the overridden behaviour, for example.

Comment: Lol that's right, I just tested this in three languages. I guess I never thought about it.. thanks!

Comment: i want to use method test of  class A for  object b of class B

Comment: @AshvinSingh: From which code? I think my answer is pretty clear here: you can't get to the A implementation of `test` from outside the code in B. Within B, you can call `super.test()`. If you want the original implementation to still be available, just don't override it in B...

Comment: @AshvinSingh: Please don't just write a comment which doesn't make sense on its own. Write the *whole* comment in one go. Or ideally, do this in the *question* in the first place. Comments aren't really meant to be used like this. If you feel you've still got a valid question which isn't covered either by my answer or the question which your question has been marked a duplicate of, post a new question - but put significant effort into making it a *good* question which gives all the context you're interested in, right from the start.

Comment: @Jon Skeet no you are not allowed to do any changes in test method  ,only object b is to be tested on parameter of test method in class A,not for other objects of class B

Comment: @AshvinSingh: Sorry, that comment makes very little sense. It sounds like you really need to ask a new question, but put enough time into it to make it a *good* question. (I find that writing a good question usually takes about half an hour. If you find that you're done after only 5 minutes, that probably shows you need to put more time into making it as polished as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

The class itself is error. You should not add the parenthesis while defining class names.
You can use either object type casting or call `super.test()` in the `test` method of class B

```
class A
 {
 test()
 {}
 }

   class B extends A
  {
  test()
  {
   super.test()   // calls the test() method of base class
   }
   }


  B b=new B();
```

Comment: I was thinking of casting as well, but I definitely don't think you can assign a superclass to a subclass variable.

Comment: I think it will work. I have did this before. But I feel type casting is not recommended.

Comment: I tried that as well, it doesn't work. It is an implicit type cast: `((B)A)` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah. You are right. Only derived class object can type caste to base class object. I didn't check it.

Comment: Then I think first method is only possible

Comment: no you are not allowed to do any changes  in test method ,only object b is to be tested on parameter of test method in class A.not for other objects of class B

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to call base class method using derived class object.

`b.super.test()`